# restrict root access to a table in postgresql

Tags: c#, postgresql, security

I have An C# application and an Postgresql database and our client wants that content of some tables to be not accessible/readable, i.e. data they contain to remain secret/confidential, even for Postgresql root. I want to avoid data encryption as this will make debugging very difficult. Related to this, another problem is that when I to connect to a database on local host 127.0.0.1, no password is required, even for Postgresql root. So, how can I make a Postgresql table that can't be read by another Postgresql user, not even by Postgresql root?

Answer (score 0):

There is no user `root` in PostgreSQL.

There is no way to keep a superuser from reading table data.

To force password authentication for local connections, change the corresponding lines in `pg_hba.conf` from `trust` to `md5` and reload.

Comment: In case of local connections, problem is that anybody accessing that computer could change back "md5" to "trust" in pg_hba.conf.

Comment: Nevertheless, I have changed in pg_hba.conf everything from "trust" to "md5" and a short experiment with pgAdmin3 showed that password is still not required in case of local connections. I even restarted the PC.

Comment: You probably have a password file created by pgAdmin III.